# Ignore errors when force:source:push

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Our ISV team has a developer org full of testing stuff (not meant to be included in the managed package we generate).

In order to stop all working in the same org, we would like to use scratch orgs.
We followed all the steps described there : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/07/migrating-existing-projects-salesforce-dx.html

We build our ISV on top of FinServ package, so because of the dependencies, I installed FinServ on the scratch org before trying the `force:source:push`.

But there are thousands of errors, some of them related to FinServ whereas we can not edit its code.

*Example:

> `force-app\main\default\classes\ccCmpUtils.cls`
>   Page CommunitiesSelfRegConfirm does not exist (of course there is no dependency between this apex class and the SFDC generated vf page)

And this is just an example, lots of "null error".

I tried using -g to ignore warnings but at the end, our source are never imported/visible in the scratch org.

Is there a way/commands allowing to pull all the content of the project ( and not only an unmanaged package content ) and to push it to a scratch org , ignoring the errors , to have a scratch org with metadata in the exact state than our developer org  ?

If not, do SFDC plan to provide tools working for ISV providers ?

Comment: You might be interested in entering the org shape pilot, which looks to be salesforces solution to this issue. Afaik (I haven't had time to properly explore the options & resources), it allows you to create a file based on an org with settings based on the target orgs settings, and then create a scratch org based off those settings. It won't fix everything, but it could help depending on the options & where your errors are.

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_pilot_shape.htm